# Need to replace ip and hostname in /etc/hosts file

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed

my /etc/hosts looks something like below

```
1.2.3.4 abc.xyz.com # comment section
2.3.4.5 bcd.xyz.com # comment section
2.3.4.6 cde.xyz.com # comment section
```

host name will be user input, I want to read /etc/hosts, find if this entry exists, if it does replace with the new host provided by user again and replace the ip for the new host and host name.. I want to retain comments after editing.
Like
    "test.sh -replace abc.xyz.com -with qwe.xyz.com"

Output :

```
5.6.7.8 qwe.xyz.com #comment section
```

Comment: while *host name will be user input* - where does new IP come from?

Comment: I have a method to ping the host and get extract the ip.

Answer (score 1):

Simple **`sed`** substitution:

```
sed -Ei 's/^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+ abc\.xyz\.com/5.6.7.8 qwe.xyz.com/' /etc/hosts
```

The final `/etc/hosts` contents:

```
5.6.7.8 qwe.xyz.com # comment section
2.3.4.5 bcd.xyz.com # comment section
2.3.4.6 cde.xyz.com # comment section
```